# Compilation with Optimization and Debug switches - any reduction in performance?

Tags: performance, optimization, gcc

Using gcc on Ubuntu, should there be a (speed) performance difference if compiling the code with:

```
gcc -O3 prog.c
```

or:

```
gcc -O3 -g prog.c
```

IOW, does the insertion of debug information slows down the executable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it can slow down the executable a bit. Also, stack and control flow-related optimizations will be disabled when using -g.

See this SO post as a possible duplicate: [How Does The Debugging Option -g Change the Binary Executable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89603/how-does-the-debugging-option-g-change-the-binary-executable)