# Is there any side effect to compile production code with gcc debug options?

Tags: c++, gcc

For gcc flags like --coverage, do they have any side effect, for example run time performance penalty?

If not then can I just leave them in the common makefile and use them to build production code?

Gcc document doesn't say anything about this.

This question 
[How Does The Debugging Option -g Change the Binary Executable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89603/how-does-the-debugging-option-g-change-the-binary-executable)

explains -g, but how about --coverage？I guess the answer is yes, the added instrument code must cost quite a bit at runtime

Comment: Maybe you should go and ask this on a gentoo-user forum.   Ok, I'll show myself out now...

Comment: Coverage code costs space and time.  You probably don't want them in production code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sup>*Transferring a succinct comment as an answer so maybe there can be closure on the question.*</sup>

Coverage code costs space and time. You probably don't want them in production code.

Debug information isn't loaded normally; the cost is much smaller (basically, zero).