# PTRACE_TRACEME - Operation not permitted error?

Tags: c, debugging, breakpoints, memory-address

I try to develop my own debugger.
I used in child space the code:

```
//child process asks the OS kernel to let its parent trace it
if (ptrace(PTRACE_TRACEME, 0, NULL, NULL) == -1) {
      perror("ptrace_traceme");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

but I got the error:

> ptrace_traceme: Operation not permitted

**using Ubuntu 22.04.**

I tried two ways:

```
/proc/sys/kernel/yama/ptrace_scope change to 1
```

and:

```
echo 0 | sudo tee /proc/sys/kernel/yama/ptrace_scope
```

they didn't work, do you have another way or are you faced with that issue?
Thanks for your helps!

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89603/how-does-the-debugging-option-g-change-the-binary-executable

Comment: That is not related, my bottom line is:
How to know where to put the breakpoint in terms of understanding and not written code, for example, if you put a breakpoint in line 23 to us it seems simple, in line 23 in the source code, but how does the debugger know honestly where line 23 is? I would appreciate a verbal explanation

Answer (score 1):

When you compile an executable with debugging symbols enabled (`cc -g ...`), the compiler embeds a variety of metadata in that binary that describe variables and functions and include information about source code lines.

`gdb` reads this metadata in order to allow you to do things like listing your code, or setting a breakpoint at a specific line/function.

If you were writing your own debugger and wanted to provide the same features, you would need to introduce support for reading this metadata. See the [Wikipedia article on DWARF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DWARF) for an introduction to how this metadata is stored.