# Cannot execute program if using boost (C++) libraries in debug-version on WinXP

Tags: c++, windows, dll, boost, side-by-side

I'm using boost for several C++ projects.  I recently made a upgrade (1.33.1 to 1.36, soon to 1.37), since then I cannot run any debug-builds anymore.

To be sure that no other project issues remain, I've created a minimum test-project, which only includes boost.thread, and uses it to start one method.  The release build can be started, the debug build cannot, although the *Dependency Walker* shows that all required libraries are found (this also means that the required MS Debug CRT is found in the SxS directory).

On startup I only get:

> Die Anwendung konnte nicht richtig initialisiert werden (0xc0150002).
>   Klicken Sie auf "OK", um die Anwendung zu beenden.

Which means nothing more than "failed to initialize app".  An internet research primarily lead to [an MS Office installation problem](http://support.microsoft.com/?scid=kb%3Ben-us%3B822520&x=16&y=11), which recommends to perform a repair of WinXP.

So, beside the repair setup (which I think will not help as I'm talking about debug-dll issues), any ideas?

Ah, before I forget: Absolutely the same source-code leads to no errors on the build-machine (i.e., DLLs can be registered, means executed).  So it's obviously an installation problem, but as the DLLs *are* there, and dependency-walker finds it, what else have I forgotten?

(**edit**) Well, I have not yet resolved my problem, but thanks to deemok I'm a step further.  For the sake of reducing misunderstandings I give some clarifications below:

- The program fails to run on the *developer*-machine
- I am working with an *installed* VS2005 (it's a VC++8 project)
- I used the boost-setup from [BoostPro](http://www.boostpro.com/products/free), compiled all possible build-versions, and I double-checked that they are there (otherwise I'd already get linker-errors during build).
- and I double-checked any corner of include/lib/bin configuration I can think of -- as boost uses auto-linking on windows, with a special naming convention, the build or start-up would have failed, with a much more comprehensible error-message.
- I *cannot* use *static linking*, as boost.thread requires dynamic linking for DLL projects (I maybe could mess around here, but as this problem seems to happen only on my machine, I do not want to mess with this, as I'm sure the boost-guys had a reason to place that check in there in the first place)
- As I wrote, I checked with Dependency Walker, and it says everything is just fine.

Currently it seems to be an error in the boost-dll (maybe incorrect Manifest), will check that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you are using the *pre-built* libraries from BoostPro? If so, your environment might somehow be slightly different to the one they were built in (TR1 feature pack or not, etc). Perhaps best to try [building Boost yourself](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/more/getting_started/windows.html#or-build-binaries-from-source) in your specific environment.

Comment: No, not pre-built.  The installer just downloads the source, and then starts building boost for the compilers and configuration you select.  So, identical for sure.

Comment: I checked, you got me there.  Must have been remembering some older times where I've built all of boost myself.

No I did the same for the boost-versions I need now, and it works.

Still, why do the Boost-Pro DLLs fail just on my PC?

Nevermind.

Answer (score 3):

It's a [Side-by-Side](http://blogs.msdn.com/rchiodo/archive/2007/04/09/the-next-level-of-dll-hell-sxs.aspx) (SxS) issue – simply copying the DLLs is not enough anymore.

Regarding your specific problem concerning the Debug build, see: [Running vc2008 debug builds on non-dev machines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/264385/running-vc2008-debug-builds-on-non-dev-machines)

Short answer:

> You can't, because there's no installer redist for the debug runtime (and in fact the software license forbids distributing it, so you'd be breaking the EULA even if you did get something put together).

So, you'll need to install Visual Studio there.

However, if you still want to try without taking that path, you could read [puetzk's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/264385/running-vc2008-debug-builds-on-non-dev-machines#264406) in its entirety.

Or, you could try to [link everything statically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/264385/running-vc2008-debug-builds-on-non-dev-machines#264461).

Comment: Thanks for your ideas, it really seems to be an SxS issue, but not for the debug-runtime (other non-boost-using projects work...).  Statical linking is not possible, for the reasons outlined in the edit.

Answer (score 1):

This might turn out to have nothing to do with SxS. I suggest checking the Event Log for SxS error messages and using dependency walker to check for most probable DLL dependency issue, or one of the DLLs is returning FALSE from its DllMain (for whatever reason).

Also, enabling loader snaps:

> gflags -i yourapp.exe +sls

might shed extra light when run under debugger (or dependency walker for that matter).

Note: gflags is part of [Windows debugging tools](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/DevTools/Debugging/default.mspx).

Comment: Thanks for the hint with the EventLog, I completely forgot about that.  It shows me an error for the boost-DLL, just can't make sense out of it -- yet.

Answer (score 0):

Get yourself the [dependency walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/). Open your application exe in it. It will show you all the dlls that your application needs but can't load/access.

If that's not enough, you can also profile your app with the dependency walker, which will give you a lot of output to find out where the problem is.

[edit]
since you only have problems with the debug build:
make sure that when you upgraded boost, you also rebuilt not just the release binaries but also the debug binaries of boost. And of course, make sure that the debug build was built with the same version of VisualStudio than you're using now.

And make sure that the include paths (tools->options->projects and solutions->VC++ directories) are correct: the paths to the latest boost version must be there, not maybe to an older version.

Comment: Thanks for your ideas, but the Dependency Walker was the first tool I tried.  And due to the autolinking-feature and strict naming-conventions of boost it would not be possible to load the wrong DLL.