# C++ Debug and Release build configurations

Tags: c++

Currently using VSCode, g++, C++20, Ubuntu 20.04 Lts.

What compiler flags can I use for release builds and debug builds separately? Do I turn off every optimization flag for debug builds? Or does it not really matter? I would appreciate any advice, recommendations, or feedback as I couldn't find much on my own.

Comment: Use `-O0` (no optimisations) or `-Og` (only debugger-friendly optimisations) for debug builds. Debugging with higher optimisation levels is frustrating.

Comment: In some situations also -Og optimizes to strong. I have seen optimizing my lambdas away and also some std::visit calls are gone somewhere :-) There is only -O0 the solution...

Answer (score 1):

> Do I turn off every optimization flag for debug builds?

Yes, I would say that is the best way to go, and it does really matter! Depending on your code, your understanding of the compiler/debugger and level of optimisation chosen, the experience of debugging it will vary from mildly annoying to frustrating and almost useless. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7509066/1719926) gives a synopsis of the different levels for gcc and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69250/why-does-a-c-c-program-often-have-optimization-turned-off-in-debug-mode) has several answers going into more detail about optimisations.

As a summary, the compiler is in general allowed to modify your code in any way it sees fit, as long as it still behaves [as if](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/as_if) all your statements were executed exactly as written. In practice, `-O1` already enables dozens of techniques and `-O2` and `-O3` will probably leave almost nothing untouched, which makes it harder to pinpoint issues because:

- Stepping through code may visit statements in a different order or skip them entirely, also hindering the use of breakpoints;
- Function calls may disappear because they were inlined, and no longer be callable from the debugging prompt;
- Local variables tend to have shorter lifetimes than in your source code, so you can't always query their values.

I personally build with CMake and primarily use two of its build types:

- `Debug` (`-g`): No optimisations, compiles runtime `assert` statements;
- `RelWithDebInfo` (`-O2 -g -DNDEBUG`): Fast code without these assertions that is harder to debug, but suitable for performance analysis once your program is working correctly.